# React leaflet too much refresh map with context update value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, next.js, react-leaflet

I have a map and a list filtered in another component that displays the markers present. When I execute map.on ('moveend') to have the list of markers present I have a refreshing problem.

I have a context which contains 2 array. A filtered array and an array containing my markers. When I execute the function to update my filtered list I have several hundred data refreshed and the page crashes.

In my component which creates the map it only retrieves the default list of markers. It is in another component that I display my filtered markers.

I would like not to resume my map because the data inside does not change, my marker list is still present even if the map moves I only want to update an array of my context to display the list in another component

filteredListComp the array where is the datas is display in an other components

```
map.on('moveend', function(e){
  if(e.target.getBounds().contains(obj)) {
     filtered.push(m)
     setListCompContext(prevState => ({...prevState, filteredListComp: filtered }))
  } 
})
```

my initial context at root project:

```
const [listDefaultCompContext, setListDefaultCompContext] = useState({
   defaultListComp: [],
   filteredListComp: []
})
```

```
<ContextApp.Provider value={[listDefaultCompContext, setListDefaultCompContext]}>
    <DefaultLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </DefaultLayout>
</ContextApp.Provider>
```

Comment: What exactly is `setListCompContext` - did you mean `setListDefaultCompContext` or are these indeed 2 separate functions?  Where are these markers being rendered?  What version of react-leaflet are you using?

Comment: setListCompContext is a function for update my context, setListDefaultCompContext is the initial state of my context. I have edit the post. The problem is resolv

Comment: If you solved your problem then please post the solution as an answer so that others who come across it know that it has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the dynamic import of next.js which made a mount of my component. When I moove the map the component is always mount.

The first thing I did was create an anonymous function at the level of my page's imports.

In my component of the page I have a useEffect which does a require () of my component in order to avoid the windows is not defined.

And in my mapLeaflet component I have a useEffect which handles the map.on ('moveend') event so that it avoids having too many refreshes

```js
Component of my page at the level of import:
import xxxx from 'xxxx';
...
let MapLeaflet = () => {
    return <Spin />
}
....
import xxxx from 'xxxx';

/***************/
Inside my functional component of my page

const myFunctionalComponent = () => {

     useEffect(() => {
        MapLeaflet = require('components/s/MapLeaflet').default

        return () => {
            /* Destroy */
        }
    }, [])

}

/***************/
And in my leafletComponent inside my MapContainer

const MapLeaflet = (props) => {
   <MapContainer
   center={mapCenter}
   zoom={12}
   scrollWheelZoom={true}
   style={{ height: props.size, width: '100%', zIndex: '0' }}
   >

      <LMapContent />

   </MapContainer>
}

const LMapContent = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        // Mount

        // Map events
        map.on('moveend', (ev) => {
          ...code
        })

        return () => {
            /* Destroy */
        }
    }, [])

}
```